# Django ORM query by related name

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to query all the customer of a particular seller/user

This is my sell model

```
class Sell(models.Model):
    entry_for = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sell_entry_for'
    )
    paid_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sell_customer',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

and this is my query

```
user = User.objects.filter(
    sell_entry_for__id=<user id>
)
```

and return empty  but I have many entries for the user

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi there, but your customer is your user model right? maybe your query should be something like `Sell.objects.filter(entry_for_id=customer_id)`, or maybe I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: What is `customer_id`? In code above only `seller_id` is defined.

Comment: sorry, customer id means seller id.

Comment: I have coorrected that, I want to query users, not all the entry of sell models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id_here)

# now you want to get all related Sell objects with that user

sells = user.sell_entry_for.all()

# now you can iterate over sells to get paid_by users

for sell in sells:
    print(sell.paid_by)
```